# How to download the excel file which has no link in Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, excel, beautifulsoup

I want to download a excel file from a website. However, there is no link for that file after I check the HTML codes.

The file I download after I click "Excel Output" button in the web page is corrupted because it is just saved the HTML table as the excel file.

Here is the HTML code of that excel output button

```
                <th colspan="4">

                    <a onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer';" onmouseout="this.style.cursor='default';" onclick="alert('To open the Excel document, please Save/Save As first');window.open(window.location+'&excel=Y');">

                <font color="blue">Excel Output</font></a></th>
```

Can I use Beautifulsoup to download the file under this situation? If yes, then how?

Comment: Just add `&excel=Y` to the end of the URL of the document you are parsing and fetch it again, the content of the response should be an Excel file.

Comment: Can you tell me how to find the URL of the document? Is it in the Script?@PauloScardine

Comment: @Fangyuan, use inspect element, click the button and analyze the request url in network

Comment: @AeroBlue I tried, but all those activities are png files.

Comment: Are you able to share a link to the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not providing the original site URL it is only a wild guess but look at this JS fragment in the "onclick" attribute:

```
window.open(window.location+'&excel=Y');
```

It is appending `&excel=Y` to the current URL and opening a new window. So my educated guess is that the URL you have to download is the same URL where you got this HTML with `&excel=Y` added to the end.

Suppose you fetching this HTML from `https://example.com/report/?year=2018`: just go straight to `https://example.com/report/?year=2018&excel=Y` instead.

This should get you your spreadsheet, but only if it is really an MS Excel file - there is this old trick of outputting HTML with a file name ending in XLS and MS Excel will happily open it as it was a real MS Excel spreadsheet.

> Thank you! I think your answer exactly describes my situation. I'm sure this is not a real MS Excel file, and it is just an HTML ending in XLS. Can I still download it as a excel file? – Fangyuan

Don't mind testing if it works and figuring it out by yourself: I will do this for you. Let me create a file using a simple editor like Notepad++. I will add the following HTML table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now I will save it as `foo.xls`, locate it in Windows explorer and double click. Voila! This opens MS Excel with the following warning:

[image]

And when I click "yes" it opens OK:

[image]

So yes, download the file and save it with a name ending in `.xls`. If it is a real Excel file it will open OK, if it is an HTML table it will display the warning but will also open OK if you click "Yes".

Ok, what if it is an HTML table and you don't want the warning? You can parse it using BeautifulSoup and use a package like `pandas` or `xlwt` to create a real Excel file. I will not cover the conversion in this answer, this step deserves its own question.

Comment: Thank you! I think your answer exactly describes my situation. I'm sure this is not a real MS Excel file, and it is just an HTML ending in XLS. Can I still download it as a excel file?

Comment: @Fangyuan Check my update, the answer was too big for a comment. :-)